# Usage of velocity.js animations in React

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs, velocity.js

Can i use **velocity.js** animations within **React** components without integrating it without **velocity-react** library ? 
I don't like that by default, when the component is mounted, the final state of the animation is shown. How can i make animation to run on component load ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**simple example:**

1. import velocity

   ```
   import Velocity from 'velocity-animate';
   ```
2. then start animation in componentDidMount

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   class VelocityExample extends Component {
       componentDidMount(){
            Velocity(this.refs.block,{ scale: 2 },500)
            .then(e=>console.log('animation complete'))
       }
       render(){
           return <div ref="block" >VelocityExample</div>;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: link is broken can you plz check